# Java: prevent an object reference from being used outside a method

Tags: java

I've defined an interface `RecordVisitor`, declared as follows:

```
public interface RecordVisitor<K, V, Result> {
    public Result visit(Record<K, V> rec);
}
```

The idea is that implementations of `visit` will get called with a Record object, do their logic, and return a result.  I would like to prevent implementations from stashing away the `rec` value and using it outside of the `visit` invocation.

The only way I've thought to do this is by adding state to `Record`, and throwing `IllegalStateException` if any method is called on the record object while it is not "active".  Then I would write dire warnings into the javadoc, and hope that implementers read it.

Is there a more robust way to prevent using the `Record` object from being used outside of the `visit` method?  If possible, I'd like to build an interface that results in compile-time errors if the contract is violated.

Comment: Can you make `Record` immutable? If not, how about making a defensive copy?

Comment: Can you just avoid giving Record any public methods that mutate it? That seems like the easiest, most OO way of doing it.

Comment: If someone invokes your function and has to pass a Record into it, there is nothing you can do about the object that they control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to prevent an implementor from storing a reference to an object as part of their implementation of `visit`.

However, there is a bigger philosophical issue here.  If you don't trust the code that implements the `RecordVisitor` interface, then why are you using that code?  If you do, then why is it a problem if that code keeps a reference to an object?

> The only way I've thought to do this is by adding state to Record, and throwing IllegalStateException if any method is called on the record object while it is not "active".

If you don't trust the programmers who are implementing your `RecordVisitor` interface, this still isn't enough.  There's nothing to prevent the implementor from creating a new method

```
public void foo() {
    this.rec.activate();
    // Do something, and there is no IllegalStateException
    this.rec.deactivate();
}
```

which to `Record` will appear as an invocation from inside `visit` but won't actually be from inside `visit`.

Comment: Fortunately `Record` is an interface, and the implementation is a private nested class.  The activate/deactivate methods would be declared there, out of reach of any `RecordVisitor`s.  ¶  I kinda figured that would be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, take the advice from @AdamMihalcin to heart.

Now, if you still want to control the access to the `Record` object, take a look at Java's `Proxy` class and its associated `InvocationHandler`.  This allows you to create a proxy object that has the Record interface (assuming Record is an interface).  The `InvocationHandler` attached to the Proxy would then forward all calls to methods on the interface to the real `Record` object.  When the call to the visitor returned, you can then call a method such as `invalidate()` on your `InvocationHandler` to instruct it to stop forwarding calls to the real Record object.

Here's an example of what the InvocationHandler might look like.

```
package test.proxy ;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler ;
import java.lang.reflect.Method ;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy ;

public class CancelableObjectInvocationHandler
        implements InvocationHandler
{
    private Object _realObject ;

    public CancelableObjectInvocationHandler ( Object realObject )
    {
        _realObject = realObject ;
    }

    public Object invoke ( Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args )
            throws Throwable
    {
        Object ret = null ;

        if ( method.getName ( ).equals ( "equals" ) )
        {
            // If we are invoking the equals method, we have to compare the
            // Invocation Handlers since the Proxies forward the method call
            boolean isEquals = true ;
            if ( isEquals )
            {
                isEquals = ( args[0] instanceof Proxy ) ;
            }
            if ( isEquals )
            {
                Proxy otherProxy = (Proxy) args[0] ;
                isEquals = this.equals ( Proxy.getInvocationHandler ( otherProxy ) ) ;
            }
            return new Boolean ( isEquals ) ;
        }
        else if ( null != _realObject )
        {
            // The object is active, so execute the method call.
            ret = method.invoke ( _realObject, args ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException (
                    "Attempt to access an invalidated Object" ) ;
        }

        return ret ;
    }

    public Object getRealObject ( )
    {
        return _realObject ;
    }

    protected void invalidate ( )
    {
        _realObject = null ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `getRealObject` is a good idea in this case. ;-)

Comment: Actually it shouldn't make too much difference as the Proxy object that is being passed in only responds to the methods in the interfaces it proxies.  But you are right, in this case there is probably very little reason to have the `getRealObject()` method.  :-)

Comment: The malicious user can get the Invocation Handler by calling `Proxy.getInvocationHandler` and then call the method `getRealObject` in order to get the reference. That makes quite a difference in this usecase.

Comment: @A.H. Agreed.  In the original setting where this was used that wasn't as big an issue.